# Laravel - Form POST method issue

Tags: php, laravel, post

I'm pretty new with laravel Framework.

The issue is that I have defined a simple controller tp function when the form button clicked.

My form is

```
 <form url="{{ action('loginController@login') }}" method="POST">   
      <input type="text" name="username"  />
      <input type="password" name="password"/>      
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>   
    </form>
```

My routes are;

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('login');
});

Route::post('/login, loginController@login');
```

loginController.php

```
public function login(Request $req)
    {


        echo 'blah';
    }
```

The issue is that when I click the button nothing happens but an error

```
Whoops, `looks like something went wrong.`
```

Can someone help please

note: went over the other similar issues but did not have any progress. If someone able to help it is greatly appreciated

Ty

edit:

my stack trace is somewhat

```
NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8912:
in compiled.php line 8912
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8264
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8212
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8207
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2419
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3286
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9948
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2366
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2350
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: FYI, you are missing CSRF token - `{{ csrf_field() }}` add this inside form

Comment: First, go to your **.env** file and set `APP_DEBUG` to `true`. Then submit the form again - and you should see a specific cause for your problem, instead of the generic headline. It's a `POST` submit, so it might be you're having a `TokenMismatchException` thrown. Look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-introduction).

Comment: {{ csrf_field() }}  is already in the form. I havent quoted it here. Sorry

Comment: can you post the stack trace , enable debug mode as told by "lesssugar"

Comment: APP_DEBUG is set to true. but nor any error showing other than the one mentioned

Answer (score 1):

In your routes.php single qoute is missing in login route. It should be like this -

```
Route::post('/login', 'loginController@login');
```

And Can you please replace your code with this -

```
<form action="{{ url('login')}}" method="POST">
{!! csrf_field() !!}   
      <input type="text" name="username"  />
      <input type="password" name="password"/>      
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>   
    </form>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: are you sure that single quote is missing? can you recheck ?

Comment: @HarindaSamarasekara : what's the issue you getting now?

Comment: @jaysingkar:Please check this -  Route::post('/login, loginController@login');

Comment: I'm sorry , actually I checked your route, you have missed a single quote. corrected now